# Ether contract address

Tags: ether

Tokens have contract addresses, see https://support.metamask.io/kb/article/24-what-is-a-token-contract-address

But is there some "base" contract that manages the sending of plain vanilla ether?

Answer (score 2):

No. Ether is the basic currency, it managed by whole Ethereum network.

Almost(see comments) any interaction with contract is actually sending of ether(maybe 0) plus some data.

Comment: Thank you. So does this mean if I start my own test network blockchain then the origin block will not have any code in it?

Comment: Yes. Genesis block only contains some configuration data and balances of wallets.

Comment: @AndreyPutilin A small edit to consider for technicality: to interact with `constant` methods (and nothing else) in contracts does not require a transaction and thus does not involve sending any ether (not even a 0 ether transaction). So "Any interaction with a contract *that modifies the blockchain* is actually ..."